# Views Custom Field Handlers tokens

Tags: tokens, views

I am using simple views custom field handler. And I would like to make list of custom tokens for this $data array I have. How could I do that?

```
class custom_views_handler_field_hostname extends views_handler_field {

  function render($value) {

     $location = get_some_data_from_outside;

     foreach ($location as $key => $value) {
      $data [] =  $key. ': ' . $value;
    }

    if (!is_array($value)) {
      return theme('item_list',
          array(
            'items' => $data,
            'title' => NULL,
            'type' => 'ul'
          ));
    }
  }
```

Comment: See [`hook_token_info()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_token_info/7)

Comment: Are you sure I need to use that? And not views token functions? like document_self_token and add_self_token?

Answer (score 0):

The first hook, `hook_token_info()`, is used to declare any custom tokens.

```
    /**
 * Implements hook_token_info().
 */
function module_name_token_info() {
  $info = array();
  // Define a new token type.
  $info['types']['my_custom_tokens'] = array(
    'name' => t('My custom tokens'),
    'description' => t('A token type for my custom tokens.'),
  );
  // Define any new tokens.
  $info['tokens']['my_custom_tokens']['my_cool_token'] = array(
    'name' => t('My cool token'),
    'description' => t('A token I use to show that I am cool.'),
  );
  return $info;
}
```

We are creating our own custom token type here too but if you just want to put your token in an already existing type, you can get a list of the existing tokens and types by calling `token_get_info().`

Now that our new token is good and defined, we just need to give it some content with `hook_tokens().`

```
     /**
     * Implements hook_tokens().
     */
    function module_name_tokens($type, $tokens, array $data = array(), array $options = array()) {
      $replacements = array();

      if ($type == 'my_custom_tokens') {
        // Loop through the available tokens.
        foreach ($tokens as $name => $original) {
          // Find our custom tokens by name.
          switch ($name) {
            case 'my_cool_token':
              // Work out the value of our token.
              $value = 'Whatever we want the token to be';
              // Give our token it's value!
              $replacements[$original] = $value;
              break;
          }
        }
      }
   return $replacements;

}
```

That's it! Our token should now be available and appear in the list of tokens wherever tokens are available.

Comment: This doesnt seem useful at all? I am not talking about normal tokens but views tokens, also called replacement patterns in UI.

Comment: This solution works for anywhere you can use tokens, except views.   The goal is to get them to show up under replacement patterns in the views_field_config_ui_form